# How to prevent HTTP 404 for a custom action in an odata controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have an `ASP.Net` `WebApi2` project hosting odata both `ApiController` and `ODataController`.

And I want to add a custom action in an `ODataController`.

I saw this seems to be achievable by either adding `[HttpPost]` attribute on the desired action, or by configuring the [ODataConventionModelBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder%20(v=vs.118).aspx) with a specific [FunctionConfiguration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.builder.functionconfiguration(v=vs.118).aspx) when using the [MapODataServiceRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.odata.extensions.httpconfigurationextensions.mapodataserviceroute(v=vs.118).aspx).

To distinguish between odata routes and webapi routes we use the following scheme :

- odata  : http://localhost:9292/myProject/odata
- webapi : http://localhost:9292/myProject/api

I tried both these solution without success which all led to get an **HTTP 404** result.

My custom action is defined as following:

```
public class SomeModelsController : ODataController
{
    //...

    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        //...
        return Ok(data);
    }

    public IHttpActionResult MyCustomAction(int parameterA, int parameterB)
    {
        //...
        return Json(data);
    }

    //...
}
```

So as you guessed it, the Get call on the controller perfectly work with odata. However the MyCustomAction is a bit more difficult to setup properly.

Here is what I have tried :

1. Setting an [HttpPost] attribute on MyCustomAction

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public IHttpActionResult MyCustomAction(int parameterA, int parameterB)
   {
       //...
       return Json(data);
   }
   ```

   I also tried decorating MyCustomAction with the `[EnableQuery]` attribute.
   Also, I tried adding the `[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]` attribute on the method without changes.
2. Configuring the ODataConventionModelBuilder

   ```
     private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
     {
         var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder
         {
             Namespace = "MyApp",
             ContainerName = "DefaultContainer"
         };
         // List of entities exposed and their controller name
         // ...
         FunctionConfiguration function = builder.Function("MyCustomAction ").ReturnsFromEntitySet<MyModel>("SomeModels");
         function.Parameter<int>("parameterA");
         function.Parameter<int>("parameterB");
         function.Returns<MyModel>();

         return builder.GetEdmModel();
     }
   ```

   Also tried decoration of MyCustomAction with `[EnableQuery]`, `HttpPost` and `[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]` attributes.

I still get **HTTP 404** result.

My query url is as follow:
`http://localhost:9292/myProject/odata/SomeModels/MyCustomAction?parameterA=123&parameterB=123`

I also tried to POST parameters on
`http://localhost:9292/myProject/odata/SomeModels/MyCustomAction` with the same result. Actually with or without parameters I get **HTTP 404** status.

Comment: What is the request URL? It's like this http://localhost:9292/myProject/odata/Staffs/MyApp.MyCustomAction  ?

Comment: @FrancescoBozzi, I edited my question to add the query url (at the end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a working example from scratch with Visual Studio 2017.
If you want more info you can read this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions

- **Create a new ASP.Net Web Application (no .Net Core)**
- **Choose WebApi Template**
- **Install from NuGet the package Microsoft.AspNet.OData (I have used v. 6.0.0)**
- **Create a simple model class into Models folder**

TestModel.cs

```
namespace DemoOdataFunction.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int MyProperty { get; set; }

        public string MyString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- **Configure WebApiConfig**

WebApiConfig.cs

```
using DemoOdataFunction.Models;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData.Builder;
using System.Web.OData.Extensions;


namespace DemoOdataFunction
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            ODataModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.Namespace = "MyNamespace";

            builder.EntitySet<TestModel>("TestModels");

            ActionConfiguration myAction = builder.EntityType<TestModel>().Action("MyAction");
            myAction.Parameter<string>("stringPar");


            FunctionConfiguration myFunction = builder.EntityType<TestModel>().Collection.Function("MyFunction");
            myFunction.Parameter<int>("parA");
            myFunction.Parameter<int>("parB");
            myFunction.ReturnsFromEntitySet<TestModel>("TestModels");


            config.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: "ODataRoute",
                routePrefix: "odata",
                model: builder.GetEdmModel()
                );
        }
    }
}
```

- **Create the controller TestModelsController into Controllers folder**

TestModelsController.cs

```
using DemoOdataFunction.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.OData;
using System.Web.OData.Query;

namespace DemoOdataFunction.Controllers
{
    public class TestModelsController : ODataController
    {
        IQueryable<TestModel> testModelList = new List<TestModel>()
            {
                new TestModel{
                MyProperty = 1,
                MyString = "Hello"
                }
            }.AsQueryable();

        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<TestModel> Get()
        {
            return testModelList;
        }

        [EnableQuery]
        public SingleResult<TestModel> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
        {

            IQueryable<TestModel> result = testModelList.Where(t => t.MyProperty == 1);
            return SingleResult.Create(result);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult MyAction([FromODataUri] int key, ODataActionParameters parameters)
        {
            string stringPar = parameters["stringPar"] as string;

            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery(AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All, MaxExpansionDepth = 2)]
        public  IHttpActionResult MyFunction(int parA, int parB)
        {
            return Ok(testModelList);
        }
    }
}
```

- **Edit Web.config changing the handlers section in system.webServer**

web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="/*" 
          verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
          preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    [...]
</system.webServer>
```

That's all.

This is the request for MyAction:

```
POST
http://localhost:xxxx/odata/TestModels(1)/MyNamespace.MyAction
{
  "stringPar":"hello"
}
```

This is the request for MyFunction:

```
GET
http://localhost:xxxx/odata/TestModels/MyNamespace.MyFunction(parA=1,parB=2)
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. I tried both with and without namespace in url

Comment: Do you still get HTTP 404 result?

Comment: Yes, still HTTP 404

Comment: Do you tried a Get Request with the function decorated with [HttpGet]?

Comment: Yes, this is still HTTP 404

Comment: I had a few days off and only now I could test the code. You have to change the request in [http://localhost:9292/myProject/odata/SomeModels/MyApp.MyCustomAction(parameterA=123,parameterB=123)](http://localhost:9292/myProject/odata/SomeModels/MyApp.MyCustomAction(parameterA=123,parameterB=123)). I edited my answer.

Comment: I have carefully followed your example but I can't get it to work. Could you please elaborate a bit more your answer with a full working example, and the http url to use ?

Comment: Until today I've test in a my working project, but today I've create a working example from scratch and I've realized that I was missing a web.config's modify. I've edit my post with a step by step procedure.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and your quality answer. This helped me to spot some problems in my configuration and code.

Comment: If this work well for custom OData function, it appears that setting path of `System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler` in `web.config` file to `/*` instead of `*.` does prevent reaching the WebApiController. [I described my problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45586813/4306452), if you have any idea it will be of much help !

Answer (score 0):

I am using HTTP POST with route on the controller functions like below:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("{application}/{envName}/date/{offset}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(DateInfo))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SetDateOffsetForEnvironmentName(string application, string envName, string offset)
        {
        }
```

can you try setting the route on the function and then call the post method on it like this:

POST /status/environments/ATOOnline/PTH/date/0

Also try and capture a request through Fiddler and see what is being passed.