# How to setup IIS TransferRequestHandler path for both WebApi 2 and OData Controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm looking to properly configure `System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler` `path` attribute to handle **both** routes to WebApi REST actions **and** ODataController **custom** function in an ASP.NET WebApi 2 project.

My `web.config` file handlers are configured as follow in order to support custom ODataController functions call ([see my related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45275892/4306452)) :

```
    <handlers>
      <clear/>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="/*" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Note that the path is set to `/*` and **it works well** when accessing **custom** OData functions on our `ODataControllers`

Nevertheless we also have an ApiController and when we access it, IIS doesn't properly handle the request and fails with the following details :

> **HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error**
>   Internal Server Error
>
> **Detailed Error Information:**
>   **Module**       ManagedPipelineHandler
>   **Notification**     ExecuteRequestHandler
>   **Handler**  ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0
>   **Error Code**       0x800703e9

If I set the `TransferRequestHandler` `path` to `*.` [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35181260/extensionlessurlhandler-and-recursion-too-deep-the-stack-overflowed) the WebApi request get properly resolved however the ODataController request ends up not beeing found with HTTP 400 :

> **HTTP Error 404.4 - Not Found**
>   The resource you are looking for does not have a handler associated with it.
>
> **Detailed Error Information:**
>   **Module**       IIS Web Core
>   **Notification**     MapRequestHandler
>   **Handler**      Not yet determined
>   **Error Code**       0x80070002

**How can I properly configure it to handle both cases ?**

**++++ Edit : ++++**
For the sake of clarity here is the queries I use to tests my controllers :

- **Custom odata function call :** `http://localhost:xxxx/myProject/odata/SomeModels/MyNamespace.MyCustomFunction(parameterA=123,parameterB=123)`
- **Native odata GET call :** `http://localhost:xxxx/myProject/odata/SomeModels`
- **Native web api GET call:** `http://localhost:xxxx/myProject/api/SomeOtherModel?parameterC=123`

**My web api controller :**

```
public class SomeOtherModelsController : ApiController
{
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int parameterC)
        {
            // ...
            return Ok(/* some result */);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(SomeOtherModel model)
        {
            // ...
            return Ok(/* some result */);
        }
}
```

**My odata controller:**

```
public class SomeModelController : ODataController
{
        [EnableQuery]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            // ...
            return Ok(/* some result*/);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IHttpActionResult MyCustomFunction(int parameterA, int parameterB)
        {
            // ...
            return Ok(/* some result */);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public IHttpActionResult AnotherCustomFunction()
        {
            // ...
            return Ok(/* some result */);
        }
}
```

Here is the web api configuration:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

and the odata configuration :

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder
{
   Namespace = "MyNamespace"
};

builder.EntitySet<SomeModelModel>("SomeModels");
var anotherCustomFunction = builder.EntityType<SomeModelModel>().Collection.Function("AnotherCustomFunction");
anotherCustomFunction.Returns<SomeResultValue>();

var myCustomFunction = builder.EntityType<SomeModel>().Collection.Function("MyCustomFunction");
myCustomFunction.Parameter<int>("parameterA");
myCustomFunction.Parameter<int>("parameterB");
myCustomFunction.ReturnsFromEntitySet<SomeModelModel>("SomeModels");
```

Comment: Hi John-Philip, can you post your Api Controller, WebApiConfig and the http request?

Comment: Hi @FrancescoBozzi, I edited my answer for the sake of clarity. Nevertheless I already found a solution ([see my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45588695/4306452)) while I would prefer a more specific one.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution, [as proposed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311955/web-api-2-2-odata-v4-function-routing), is to add `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />` to `<system.webServer>` in the `web.config` file :

```
 <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
 </system.webServer>
```

It turns out that adding this module makes the presence of `System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler` handler unnecessary.

Therefore the following system.webServer configuration is sufficient to handle both api query and custom OData function queries :

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Nevertheless, **I'm not confortable with this solution** as I don't know exactlly what could be the effects of `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />`.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275892/how-to-prevent-http-404-for-a-custom-action-in-an-odata-controller?answertab=active#45281255), I've created a new model (AnotherModel) and a new ApiController (AnotherModelsController)

AnotherModel.cs

```
namespace DemoOdataFunction.Models
{
    public class AnotherModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int MyInt { get; set; }

        public string MyString { get; set; }
    }
}
```

AnotherModelsController.cs

```
namespace DemoOdataFunction.Controllers
{
    public class AnotherModelsController : ApiController
    {
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int parameterC)
        {
            // ...
            return Ok();
        }

        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            // ...
            return Ok("Ok");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post(AnotherModel model)
        {
            // ...
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Without any other changes both Api and OData controller works.

```
GET
http://localhost:4186/api/AnotherModels?parameterC=1

GET
http://localhost:4186/api/AnotherModels 

Post
http://localhost:4186/api/AnotherModels
{
"Id" : 1,
"MyInt" : 2,
"MyString" : "Hello"
}

GET
http://localhost:4186/odata/TestModels/MyNamespace.MyFunction(parA=1,parB=2)
```

I've also tried changing the "path" setting of web.config to * but that's fine.
I suggest you create a new project from scratch and compare it with yours.